# Custom skins engine for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, templates, themes, skin

I would like to let the users of my apps (C# + WPF) to build their own themes and skins.
What is the best way to achive that? Are there some examples or maybe some sort of "skin engine" I need to look for?

Coming from web development I usually use both XAML and images to build the UI... but in this way all sources will be "hardcoded", embedded in the main exe or into some dll...

Instead I would like to have some text files with all the parameters (like colors, spacings, dimensions, font size, etc...) and all the images contained in a folder in jpg or png format.
Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of "images" you use to build the UI? usually none of that is needed in WPF, which supports vector graphics.

Comment: What kind of users are you talking about?  Are you talking about having your users select colors/images from available options, or are they developers would could build out their own XAML Resources?  Feel free to check out [this WPF skinning library](https://github.com/brschwalm/Muren) and see if it helps.

Comment: Yes, I could design everything in code using vectors achiving better results. But I prefer to design everything in photoshop and then export pieces of interface skin, just like I usually do for web development... At this stage it seems easier, foolprof, and it allow users to better understand interface design if they want to personalize it: minor customizations just needs some jpg replacement.

Comment: Interesting link Brian, I will surely check it out!

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any pre-built skinning engines for WPF that allow users to select colors and update the application.  However I have used a similar approach to your "text files with all the parameters..." in a WPF application, and it worked relatively well.

We used an XML file with the theme colors/icons/etc. that was loaded at runtime and used to update application resources with the firm-defined colors & images.  Depending on your architecture, you could also store the skin/theme in a database.

In order for this to work, a couple suggestions:

- Define a standard set of `Colors` available for use throughout the app (e.g. LightControlColor, ControlColor, DarkControlColor, LightBackgroundColor, BackgroundColor, Dark...).  These are the colors defined in the XML file, and will be updated when the skin/theme changes.
- Define a standard set of `Brushes` that you will use in all your XAML.  These brushes will make use of the `Colors`, so a ControlBackgroundBrush could be a `SolidColorBrush` made up of one of the `Colors` (from above), or it could be a `LinearGradientBrush` made up of multiple colors.
- Use `DynamicResource` everywhere rather than `StaticResource` so that when you update your `Color` Resources based on the XML file, everything will be updated.
- You'll need to update the `Colors` in the `Application.Resources` before the main window is displayed since `DynamicResources` are evaluated when visual elements are rendered.  A splash screen is a great way to occupy the user while you're loading, parsing and merging the skin.
- We didn't have too many images, but I believe we stored the ones we did have in binary format within the XML.
- We built a separate application for creating a skin/theme.  This was distributed independently of the main app and was strictly for the purpose of creating & updating skins.

Comment: Would you mind sharing some code? How do you reference those DynamicResources in XAML? I'm just a beginner so every easy task is just like climbing a mountain :) I also read something about XAMLReader and the use of external uncompiled xaml on the web: does anybody ever had any experience with this technique?